# GetWebResponse() throws timeout exceptions after a few requests on Mono/Linux

Tags: linux, mono

I have an application that constantly sends requests to server. I use GetWebResponse() method of WebClient class for sending requests. But after a few requests, it starts throwing timeout exceptions. This happens only on Mono/Linux. The same code runs without any exceptions on .Net/Windows. Do you have any ideas what might be the problem?

Note: I tried setting Timeout and ReadWriteTimeout properties of the requests with no luck.

Comment: what version of mono?

Comment: and how are you running mono? as a normal process? or a service? or an ASP.NET website?

Comment: Mono version is 2.10.8, we are running it as a normal process.

Comment: updated my answer, did you give this a go?

Comment: Since it was a little bit difficult for us to compile Mono on ARM processor (on which the final code would run) and since the latest version we could find was 2.10.8 we tried RestSharp framework and we didn't have any problem with it. Though I'm marking your answer as accepted since it has a lot of suggestions as a solution.

Comment: mono master branch does have a lot of improvements wrt ARM compilation; if you want to read about them, check this blog: http://blog.alexrp.com/

Comment: Today I tried compiling Mono from source, but it gave the hardfb-abi error which is expected I guess. The blog post you linked mentiones about this error and says it will be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try these possible alternatives to try to solve the problem:

1. Upgrade Mono to 3.0.x. There have been a lot of fixes in the last months around WebRequests.
2. If the above doesn't help, try Mono 3.2 (as it defaults to use a new garbage collector, much faster, called SGEN).
3. If the above doesn't help, build your own Mono (master branch), as [this important pull request](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/703) has been merged recently.
4. If the above doesn't help, use the "--server" flag when calling your mono executable (this feature is only available in the last version of mono, which you need to compile from the master branch).
5. If all the above doesn't help, then CC yourself in [this bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11833), as I think I'll have time in August to implement a fix for it, and maybe it helps you.